# Drupal: menu translation with internationalization module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is "Nice Menus" working with menu translation of Internalization module ?

I've assigned different strings for each language with the "Translation Table", but the menu content is always in engish.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the Menu Translation menu is that you have to create menu items, and that if you want to translate the menu items, you have to create a separate menu item, but in the language you specify. So you have multiple entries for the same menu item but they will only show up in the language you specify. There are some screenshots of what I mean at http://drupal-translation.com/content/adding-menu

Possibly related issue: http://drupal.org/node/770970

Comment: oh ok. Then, I actually don't need it. I just want to translate the menu items strings, the menu structure should be the same...